# Email date is wrong/missing

Tags: email, smtp

In the typical email setup when an end user views the date of an email, is that supplied by the sending server or the receiving server?

Every once in a while I'll get complaints that the date on an email originating from our servers is wrong (usually something like 1900, or 1969 indicating that it's just displaying a default date). All the dates on our system are correct and it definitely does not happen all the time. I've always just assumed the problem is with the receiving end.

Can anyone shed some light on what would cause this to happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a typical email setup the `Date:` header is set by the mail client *sending* the message: It's the date on the machine where the email was composed.  A `Date` header may be added by a server along the way if it's missing (and I suppose it's possible that server presumes the epoch for email with no date).

The `Received:` headers are always added by each server the mail passes through -- Verify the dates on those to demonstrate that your servers have the correct date/time.

Comment: So why in a message addressed to two outside recipients would it happen for one and not the other?

Comment: @matthew that depends on the mail client (and servers) handling the message (Some might grab the first "Received:" date and call it that, others may just assume the epoch, and it's possible some just assign the date they first saw the message).  Short answer, as with all email questions, is "Email Sucks." :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think @vorateq7 has nailed the answer, but on a related note, I wrote up exactly *why* the date [shows up as 1969 if there is no date header](http://www.hollenback.net/index.php/ImpossibleEmailDates).  Short answer: The default is January 1, 1970, but since that's UTC, those of use behind UTC end up back in 1969.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it is the responsibility of the originating mail client which is *sending* the message to ensure that a proper `Date:` header is created. If some messages from your mail server include the header and others don't, it is because they are being originated by different clients and one is leaving out the `Date:` header.

Example: You have a contact form on a web site which uses PHP to originate a message by connecting to your MTA through SMTP. If it doesn't include the `Date:` header, your MTA probably doesn't add it (For example, qmail doesn't fix broken headers it is relaying because it encourages the practice of sending broken messages and introduces potential security holes for spammers.).

Check the originating sources of your messages which which ones are leaving the `Date:` header off. Apparently, many Microsoft mail apps have also been known to do this.